# Is it possible to have an ASP.NET application perform a timed action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm wondering if there is a way I can force the server perform a periodic action, but I am open to other solutions to this problem.

I've created a number of web pages that display internal reports to my company. A few of these reports have no search parameters and will display the same information for anybody who views them. As such, when the query is run I save the data in the server cache and display the cached data to anybody who views the page.  The query itself takes a while to run so I don't want it to run every time somebody views the page. I have a "Refresh" button on the page if anybody wants more up to date data.

So, is it possible to set a server side timer that runs the query every 30 minutes and saves the data to the cache so it can be viewed later? I've also considered storing the cached data with a `DateTime` of the last time the query was run, and if the `TimeSpan` between now and the last run is longer than 1 hour, then I'll rerun the query.  However, I'd rather have the data refresh without any sort of user action.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is called "Task Scheduling" (assuming it's a Windows server). You can write a small program that will grab the data and set up a task to run it every 30 minutes.

Comment: How would an outside program be able to update the server cache though?